# How to automatically remove data from firestore after a specific time?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an app in flutter where I have a stories section. Where users can upload stories ( Text / Images). What I want is to automatically delete the posts after one day.

What I have achieved is to delete one day ago data by checking the timestamp of the post and a simple calculation and a remove call to delete it.

But what I want to achieve is an automated process. Like data is automatically deleted after one day without checking for posts on random calls or time. Like I don't know if it's possible or not. But if someone has a solution it would be a great favour. Thakns

Comment: You have several distinct problems to solve here.  There isn't a pre-packaged solution that will do everything you want - it will require putting toegether several cloud products and writing code to put them all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before displaying an item you can check if it is posted in the last 24 hours and if not then don't display it.

To delete the items from Firestore you can set a scheduled job in the backend.
You can use cloud functions pubsub. Write a function like "every one hour find & delete the items that are created before the last 24 hours". Take a look here [Schedule functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions).

Comment: Also see https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a